How to input multiple inputs in RunnableWithMessageHistory of LangChain?
I would like to ask about LangChain for LLM in python.
I need multiple inputs with chatting history to run the model, so I tried to use RunnableWithMessageHistory but got an error.

Error in RootListenersTracer.on_chain_end callback: KeyError('input')
{'output1': 'future', 'output2': 'past'}

llm = ChatOpenAI(
    model="gpt-4o",
    temperature=0,
    max_tokens=None,
    timeout=None,
    max_retries=2,
    api_key=api_info['api_key'], 
    organization=api_info['organization']
    # base_url="...",
    # other params...
)

store = {}
def get_session_history(session_ids):
    if session_ids not in store: 
        store[session_ids] = ChatMessageHistory()
    return store[session_ids]  
    
response_schemas = [
    ResponseSchema(name="output1", description="translates first word to English"),
    ResponseSchema(name="output2", description="translates next word to English")
]
output_parser = StructuredOutputParser.from_response_schemas(response_schemas)


prompt_template_1 = ChatPromptTemplate(
    messages=[
        SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(
        "Output MUST be JSON format"
        ),
        MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="chat_history"),
        HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(
            "translates {korean_word1} and {korean_word2} to English."
            "\n{format_instructions}"
        )
    ],
    input_variables=["korean_word1", "korean_word2"],
    partial_variables={"format_instructions": output_parser.get_format_instructions()}
)

chain1 = prompt_template_1 | llm | output_parser
chain_with_history = RunnableWithMessageHistory(
    chain1,
    get_session_history,  
    history_messages_key="chat_history",  
)


word1 = '미래'
word2 = '과거'
result = chain_with_history.invoke(
    {"korean_word1": word1, "korean_word2": word2},
    config={"configurable": {"session_id": "abc123"}},
)

And I tried to use 'input_messages_key' in RunnableWithMessageHistory but also failed. Because input_messages_key allow one key only, not multiple keys.
chain_with_history = RunnableWithMessageHistory(
    chain1,
    get_session_history, 
    input_messages_key=["korean_word1", "korean_word2"], // Error Here
    history_messages_key="chat_history", 
)

Please help me to write the correct code
